# input stream to UTF-8 with japanese causing issues in java

Tags: java, javascript, csv, utf-8

I am sending data from client in chinese text with proper headers (UTF-8).  Its NOT going thorugh application/x-www-form-urlencoded (so - no key values) but I am simply doing a post with postdata using jQuery.  The data is csv string.  Here is my client header information -

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType:"text/csv; charset=UTF-8",
          url: <someURL>,
          data: csvStr,
          success: function(result){
           location.href = result// downloading the csv file
           },
         error: function(xhr) {
           //error handling
           }
    });
```

Here is my java code -

```
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
String str = null;
StringBuilder result= new StringBuilder();
while ((str= br.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line).append("\r\n");
}
```

I am opening the CSV file excel by default and have set japanese as default language there.  But I still see ?? amongst some japanese characters.  Please note that it is only happening with languages which use double byte i.e. japanese, chinese...

Thanks

Comment: May be irrelevant, but if you are sending Chinese text, why are you setting the encoding to Japanese?

Comment: Can you provide an example of `csvStr`, and the corresponding file written on the server?  Does your CSV file contain a BOM?  Also, are you invoking excel with any options that would cause it to choose an encoding other than UTF-8?

Comment: I am sorry... it was a typo - the issue happens with both chinese and japanese...

Comment: Are you sure the source data is encoded in UTF-8 (as opposed to common chinese or japanese encodings such as GB2132 or shift-JIS?) I'm not sure if it's enough to just set headers

Comment: @Mike- example string - "チケット ID,件名,優先度" 
for excel - I just made japanese as the default language in microsoft office language preferences.  I dont know anything about BOM!

Comment: @Mxyl - how could I make sure that source data is UTF-8 coded?  I simply picked some japanese data from google translator - which is working in some other scenarios.

Comment: Wait, if you're exporting to csv in excel, you might run into problems. If you open your file in notepad is the data correct? For checking the source data encoding, usually I just open it in a web browser and just pick the page encoding. If it's UTF8, it should appear as expected. I'm sure there are more sophisticated ways to do it but I don't know what they are.